# Replacing a tag with another tag based on its attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML file:

```
<p> 
  <rs key="rGR" n="1" id="id1">XXXXX</rs>
  <rs key="rGR" n="2" xml:id="id3">YYYYYY</rs>, text text texts 
  <rs key="rGR" n="3" xml:id="id4">ZZZZZZ</rs>) text text text.
  <rs key="r3"  n="1" xml:id="id30">HHHHHH</rs>text text text text text. 
text text 
  <rs key="r3"  n="2" xml:id="id31">KKKKKK</rs>
  <rs key="r3"  n="3" xml:id="id32">PPPPPPP</rs> text text text  
</p>
```

I want to replace the tag `rs[@n="1"]` with the tag `<ref>` and keep only the `@id` and for other `<rs>` with `n != 1`. And that should have some key, because I want to replace it with the tag `<ptr>` that has the attribute pointer that contains the `@id` of the `<rs>` with `n=1`.

The output should be like that:

```
<p> 
  <ref id="id1">XXXXX</ref>(text text
    <ptr pointer="id1">YYYYYY</ptr>, text text text 
    <ptr pointer="id1">ZZZZZZ</ptr>) text text text 
    <ref id="id30">HHHHHH</ref>
text text text text text. 
text text 
    <ptr pointer="id30">KKKKKK</ptr>
    <ptr pointer="id30">PPPPPPP</ptr> text text text 
  </ref>
</p>
```

I use the following syntax, but it only works if `n=1`

```
<xsl:template match="rs[@n='1']">
  <ref id="{@xml:id}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ref>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to add a second template to match the case wheh `n != 1`

```
<xsl:template match="rs[@n != '1']">
```

In fact, you could just write this because it will have a lower priority to the one with the condition

```
<xsl:template match="rs">
```

In it, you can get the `xml:id` of the `rs` with `n = 1` like so

```
<ptr pointer="{../rs[@key=current()/@key and @n=1]/@xml:id}">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="rs[@n='1']">
    <ref id="{@xml:id}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ref>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rs">
    <ptr pointer="{../rs[@key=current()/@key and @n='1']/@xml:id}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ptr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you do have a mix of `@id` and `@xml:id` attributes, try this instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="rs[@n='1']">
    <ref id="{@*[local-name() = 'id']}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ref>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rs">
    <ptr pointer="{../rs[@key=current()/@key and @n='1']/@*[local-name() = 'id']}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ptr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim for your answer, the tags are placed on the right place, but for the tag rs[@key="rGR"] the id value does not exist in both <ref> and <ptr> tags.

Comment: The second solution works well, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think that there is a problem when the tags are disordered, for example, when we have this: 
  <rs key="rGR" n="1" id="id1">XXXXX</rs>                                             <rs key="r3"  n="1" xml:id="id30">HHHHHH</rs>                                                               <rs key="rGR" n="2" xml:id="id3">YYYYYY</rs>                                                                  the rs[@id="id3"] will take the id of rs[@id="id30"]

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer to cope with random orders